# mysql | Format the CONCAT function to have small brackets

Tags: mysql, database

i have select in query

```
IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(ED.dependent_name, ED.date_of_birth))," No Dependents ") AS Dependents
```

The Result i get is like this..

[image]

Data is fine but problem with this is, it look untidy, i want to have date of birth in brackets
e-g for Employee `E-02`, i want record something like this, means enclose the date in small braces.

```
Muhammad Zubair (1998-12-15) ,Amir Khan (2000-12-15)
```

Is there any way i can update the above select statement and get the result like i want to have or any other better way to achieve a good looking result.?

MY Query:

```
SELECT 
  `E`.`employee_code` AS Employee_Code,
  E.full_name AS NAME,
  E.father_name AS Father_Name,
  IFNULL(
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      DISTINCT CONCAT( ED.dependent_name '(', ED.date_of_birth, ')')), " No Dependents " ) AS Dependents 
FROM
  (`employee` E) 
  INNER JOIN `employee_project` EP 
    ON `EP`.`employee_id` = `E`.`employee_id` 
  INNER JOIN `permanant_contacts` PC 
    ON `PC`.`employee_id` = `E`.`employee_id` 
  INNER JOIN `ml_district` MLD 
    ON `MLD`.`district_id` = `PC`.`district` 
  LEFT JOIN `dependents` ED 
    ON `ED`.`employee_id` = `E`.`employee_id` 
    AND ED.trashed = 0 
WHERE `E`.`trashed` = 0 
GROUP BY `E`.`employee_id`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have youy tried

```
CONCAT(ED.dependent_name, '(', ED.date_of_birth, ')')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CONCAT(ED.dependent_name,CONCAT('(',CONCAT(ED.date_of_birth, ')')))
```

Comment: `CONCAT` takes an arbitrary number of arguments: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat. There's no reason to call it so many times, as depicted in the other answer.